# backbone.js - Why values send in OPTIONS method?

Tags: backbone.js

I create a backbone app and a form to submit text value.

When I submit form, in "Net" tab in firebug I see:

[image]

How I can send form with **Post** method?

What need to do on server or something?

Comment: Most likely because you're trying to do a cross domain Ajax request.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli What can I do to solve?

Comment: Either look into JSONP, or CORS if it's supported. Or retrieve it using your own server as a proxy, then just make an Ajax request to your server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The options request you see is not send INSTEAD of your post request, it is called before the post request is triggered if you are in a cross-domain situation.

If you want to allow this on server side you could make your server respond with an additional HTTP header:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://your.requesting.site.url
```